# TikZ Patterns displayed incorrectly in ShareLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using Sharelatex to create a document with diagrams in it. I have a problem when using patterns as they do not look the way they should. Crosshatch looks like arrows, grid - like a set of angles, even the lines are dashed. How can I fix the way the patterns are displayed?

Here is the code that I am using and the corresponding picture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[pattern=crosshatch]  (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw[pattern=grid]  (2,0) rectangle (4,2);
    \draw[pattern=north west lines]  (4,0) rectangle (6,2);
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (6,0) rectangle (8,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have checked and the problem is not in the generated PDF but in the displayed image. So probably you should [submit a bug repport](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/issues) for the pdf renderer used by ShareLaTeX to convert the PDF to PNG.